# Implementing IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a class named `MyDictionary` which works as the dictionary class and which implements interfaces like `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` and `IDictionary`. I've manually created the interfaces and manually wrote the functionality of each method in the interface except for the `IEnumerable`, I can't think of what methods that I can implement for the `IEnumerable` interface, can someone tell me what methods I can implement for the class I'm working on ?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace lab3
{ 
    interface ICollection 
    {
        int Count { get; }
        
        int enqueue(object value);
        void dequeue(object value);
        //void CopyTo(Array array, int index);
    }
    
    interface IEnumerable 
    {
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    interface IDictionary 
    {
        bool Contains(object key);
        Boolean TryGetIndexOfKey(Object key, out Int32 index);
        void Remove(object key);
        void Add(object key, object value);
    }
    
    class MyDictionary : IEnumerable, IDictionary, ICollection
    {
        private DictionaryEntry[] items;
        private Int32 ItemsInUse = 0;
        Int32 index = -1;
  
        public MyDictionary(Int32 numItems)
        {
            items = new DictionaryEntry[numItems];
        }
        
        public bool Contains(object key)
        {
            Int32 index;
            return TryGetIndexOfKey(key, out index);
        }
        
        public Boolean TryGetIndexOfKey(Object key, out Int32 index)
        {
            for (index = 0; index < ItemsInUse; index++)
            {
                // If the key is found, return true (the index is also returned).
                if (items[index].Key.Equals(key)) return true;
            }
  
            // Key not found, return false (index should be ignored by the caller).
            return false;
        }
        
        public void Add(object key, object value)
        {
            // Add the new key/value pair even if this key already exists in the dictionary.
            if (ItemsInUse == items.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The dictionary cannot hold any more items.");
            items[ItemsInUse++] = new DictionaryEntry(key, value);
        }
        
        public void Remove(object key)
        {
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            // Try to find the key in the DictionaryEntry array
            Int32 index;
            
            if (TryGetIndexOfKey(key, out index))
            {
                // If the key is found, slide all the items up.
                Array.Copy(items, index + 1, items, index, ItemsInUse - index - 1);
                ItemsInUse--;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the key is not in the dictionary, just return.
            }
        }   
        
        public int Count { get { return ItemsInUse; } }

        public void dequeue(object value)
        {
            
        }

        public int enqueue(object value)
        {
            return -1;
        }
  
        GetEnumerator()
        {
            // Construct and return an enumerator.
            return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            dictionary.Add("Mohammed", 21);
            dictionary.Remove("Mohammed");
            Console.WriteLine("Number of elements in dictionary = {0}", dictionary.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Does dictionary contain 'Mohammed'? {0}", 
            dictionary.Contains("Mohammed"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making your own `Interfaces` instead of using the provided ones in .Net? `IEnumerable`, `IDictionary` and `ICollection` already exist.

Comment: Also why are you creating a non-generic Dictionary?  If you want a non-generic dictionary just use `HashTable` although you really shouldn't ever use non-generics if you can help it.

Comment: You can implement any methods you want, physically possible and you can :) Please be more specific about what is your question.

Comment: What would be the point of `TryGetIndexOfKey` when nothing else in the interface is defined in terms of a numeric index? There's also apparently no way of accessing a value from your dictionary based on a key value, which seems like a core requirement of a dictionary.

Comment: Is this for a class or just practice?  As Ryan said, you should really use the existing interfaces and probably the existing collection classes.  But if you really do want practice recreating it, you can just look at those interfaces to see what methods need to be implemented.

Comment: This is an assignment and we are asked to implement the methods of the interfaces manually and not use the ready made ones by .NET @DanCsharpster

Answer (score 0):

Typically a `IEnumerable` interface have a single method that returns a `IEnumerator`, just as in your example.

You do not define the `IEnumerator` interface, but it would typically look like this

```
interface IMyEnumerator{
    bool MoveNext();
    object Current {get;}
}
```

The implementation of this interface could for example contain an array and an index. `MoveNext()` increments the index and returns true if the current index is smaller than the array length. `Current` would just return the array value for the index. Note that this should be a separate class from `MyDictionary`, do not try to make a single class implement both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.

The language have various features to make it easier to use the built in `IEnumerable<T>` interface, like [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) loops and [iterator blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators).  So it is fairly rare to write your own IEnumerator from scratch, but it is worth knowing how it works under the hood. The compiler supports some duck-typing, so if you provide the correct methods some of the language features should work.

I would also note that your `ICollection` interface looks like a queue, in contrast to the build in `ICollection<T>` interface. And I find it a bit odd for a class to implement both a dictionary interface and a queue interface.

Comment: Note that `foreach` is an example where the language supports duck typing - so long as you have a `GetEnumerator` method that returns something that exposes `MoveNext` and `Current`, the compiler will work with it. You don't need to use the library types.